# Where can I ask about "Conway's Game of Life" gameplay?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question about [Conway's Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life)'s gameplay, but I can't seem to find an appropiate site for it.

The candidates are:

- [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) (I'm pretty sure it will be off-topic, because the question is not related to how the game was developed)
- [Board & Card Games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/) (This may be a possibility, although technically it's not a board nor a card game)
- [Role Playing Games](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/) (I'm not so sure about this game being an RPG)
- [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) (This one would be my best option, but I can't seem to find any `"game-of-life"` tag or something similar, so I'm not convinced)

Comment: Arqade would be my option too, you can ask in their meta to get the best answers though. (i.e. whether it fits there or not)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thank you, I have posted a similar question on their meta as you advised: [Where can I ask about “Conway's Game of Life” gameplay?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10813/where-can-i-ask-about-conways-game-of-life-gameplay)

Comment: @ShadowWizard there was a two player version of Conway's life that truly was a *game* with a goal and scoring (see [related discussion on BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/407580/conways-game-life)) which would be a Board & Card Games question. There was a computer implementation of it on Windows that I recall playing at Best Buy a decade or so ago (which would be an Arqade question if asked about that - one such implementation appears to be on Kongregate). However, the standard "zero player" cellular automata isn't so much a game but rather a CS / Math question as Arthur indicates.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Conway's Game of Life is a cellular automaton, and not really a game in the traditional — or usual — sense. (Or, if a game, it is a "zero player game", which isn't that much fun.) Depending on the specific question, it should be on topic on one of the following two sites:

- [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com) (search [`is:question "game of life"`](https://cs.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+%22game+of+life%22))
- [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com) (search [`is:question "game of life"`](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+%22game+of+life%22))

Both of these sites have a [cellular-automata](/questions/tagged/cellular-automata) tag under which questions about the Game of Life should fit.